# Perform docker build only if dockerfile is changed

Tags: git, docker, travis-ci

In travis-ci how to build docker image only if dockerfile or install.sh is changed?

Note: install.sh installs the dependencies. It contains long list of commands which dockerfile's RUN command uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(git diff --name-only ${TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE} | grep docker/Dockerfile > /dev/null)
dockerfile_status=$?

$(git diff --name-only ${TRAVIS_COMMIT_RANGE} | grep scripts/linux/bootstrap.sh > /dev/null)
bootstrap_status=$?

if [[ ${dockerfile_status} == "0" || ${bootstrap_status} == "0" ]]
then
    echo "New docker image is required, building new image"
else
    echo "New docker image is not required"
fi
```